# Javascript Function - cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, function, sorting

I'm practicing my Javascript by writing a few functions dealing with sorting and searching an unordered list . I've written a few functions already but suddenly ran into this error and I am not entirely sure why. If I could get some direction to solve this error.

Here is my code

```
function sortlength(){
    formarray();
    for(i=0;i<wordarray.length;i++){
        if(wordarray[i].length > wordarray[i+1].length){
            temp = wordarray[i];
            wordarray[i] = wordarray[i+1];
            wordarray[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
    toDOM();
}
```

Here is the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Error seems to be pointing at wordarray[i+1].length but not wordarray[i].length for some reason.

P.S formarray() forms an array from the list of words on the page and it grabs the innerHTML of each list item and toDOM() puts the array back into the page

formarray() as requested

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var words = list.getElementsByTagName("li");

var wordarray = [];

function formarray(){//forms array from list on page
    for(i=0;i<words.length;i++){
        wordarray[i] = words[i].innerHTML;
    }
    return wordarray;
}
```

wordarray from the console shows like so

```
wordarray
(200) ["servant", "watch", "wound", "women", "visitor", "stop", "lip", "excited", "scatter", "soda", "texture", "relax", "white", "thaw", "money", "noxious", "vulgar", "smiling", "imported", "embarrass", "prevent", "uptight", "powder", "base", "charge", "premium", "jump", "welcome", "ultra", "condition", "righteous", "fall", "pop", "decorate", "capricious", "alluring", "kick", "adjoining", "optimal", "amuck", "impulse", "grandiose", "regret", "sky", "absurd", "push", "unbecoming", "loaf", "amount", "wilderness", "eager", "board", "name", "guide", "difficult", "unarmed", "naughty", "puncture", "embarrassed", "symptomatic", "sand", "tick", "jumbled", "pleasant", "shake", "spotless", "womanly", "average", "steady", "motionless", "action", "valuable", "mass", "paddle", "scared", "moor", "squealing", "graceful", "drip", "tacky", "devilish", "quince", "face", "observant", "mice", "plain", "bored", "tough", "delightful", "change", "morning", "business", "adjustment", "reproduce", "spiky", "zonked", "dime", "contain", "rain", "unused", …]
```

Comment: What is `wordarray`?

Comment: You should post the code for `formarray()` as that's probably where the bug is. If it's supposed to initialize `words` it's failing to do so.

Comment: if `words` and `wordarray` are the same length, then on the last iteration of your loop you are trying to get  `wordarray[i+1].length` which will be 1 more than the actual length of `wordarray`.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the problem is with `wordarray[i+1].length`?

Comment: Definitely going to need more information. You should be logging `words` and `wordarray` using `console.log`. Debugging information like that is very useful. Also on a side note bubble sorts are extremely slow. You're probably better off using Javascript's [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: "Error seems to be pointing at wordarray[i+1].length but not wordarray[i].length for some reason." Yes, that's what the error seems to point to

Comment: maybe you should console log the length of wordarray[i].length?

Comment: wordarray[i].length
13
wordarray[i]
"heartbreaking" Not sure as to why it lands here but that's what the console outputs

Comment: wordarray[i+1].length
VM252:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:16

Comment: Gosh, there's something wrong with `wordArray[i+1].length`. The system says that the thing doesn't have a length. I wonder what `wordArray[i+1]` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to:

```
function sortlength(){
    formarray();
    for(i=0;i < wordarray.length - 1;i++){
        if(wordarray[i].length > wordarray[i+1].length){
            temp = wordarray[i];
            wordarray[i] = wordarray[i+1];
            wordarray[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
    toDOM();
}
```

I think you are going out of range. You should iterate until `wordarray.length - 2` index, so when you call `wordarray[i+1]` you are getting the last element in the last iteration. Otherwise you go out of range.

Comment: YES, the loop goes out of range so it throws an error when trying to find the length of the undefined object that is our of the array range (i+1). Thank you! :)